# How to prevent silverlight XAP from external copy & use on someone elses domain

Tags: silverlight, security

I think I dont understand this process clearly.

Let's say I create a great SL application and host it on my web page. If someone downloads th XAP he can host it on his web page since it's just a file and it will work perfectly fine I think, even if its obfuscated.

I think there are couple of ways to protect it:

1. Use authorization on my website
           (ASP.NET auth) and pass an auth token
           from it to the SL app so they at least
           will have to use my website to get
           th auth token in some way (although if
           not 2nd this could also be done in
           some unseen way, like webrequest or
           something to do everything a person would
           do to obtain th token & then it would
           again work on other domain just
           fine) and use WCF service operations with auth this auth token.
2. Use some WCF service &
               cross domain restrictions to make
               sure XAP won't work good if hosted
               like that.

Looks like if second is valid 100% protected solution there is no need to make complicated auth on web site and pass token to Silverlight, and just SL authentication can be fine.

I would like to hear your thoughts about both approaches, and maybe some other ways to help this situation.

Maybe there is a way to protect XAP so it wont work at all if it was not downloaded from some specific domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read this: http://www.youpvp.com/blog/post/Protecting-your-Silverlight-application-from-a-hijacking.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this, maybe in `Application_Startup`

```
if (Application.Current.Host.Source.Host != "mydomain.com")
    throw new ApplicationStolenException();
```

In theory someone could edit the xap file to change that string but you could obfuscate it to make it harder.

The authentication thing is not going to work. What are you going to do with that authentication token in your Silverlight app? Silverlight does not manage sessions, how are you going to prevent someone from reusing the token for ever?

The only reliable option is to have your application depend on a web service. And by depend I mean actually implementing part of the logic on the server. Otherwise it would be easy to just recreate a service that produce the same responses than yours.

As with all security related questions, it's all about balancing the risk and the investment.

Comment: yeah well.. would be too easy if obfuscating a string could be done with any definite certainty. I think if we consider a scenario of stealer of any serious skill this protection wont be worth much?

Comment: Seems like a decent protection to me (provided it's obfuscated). Edited with more info.

Comment: Yeah ofc, sorry, I meant one thing and wrote another, difference in approaches is just crossdomain file , in second approach auth is not really needed cause service is not supposed to work from download location other than my website, while first approach doesnt use crossdomain policies

Comment: dll can be decompiled with reflector and they can remove that line of code. is there a really good way to prevent this? maybe load dll runtime (I need examples of this)?